# Conditional negation probability problem

Tags: probability

K so I have an exam in probability coming up and we are going to have a similar question to this. I think this is a simple problem, but there is a twist to it:

So let's say the chance of a person smoking today in the U.S is 40%, and the chance that a person in the U.S will die of lung disease is 26%.

If a person smokes, the chance that he will die of lung disease is 55%.

What is the probability that a person does not die of lung disease, if they did not smoke.

So the formula that applies here is conditional probability I guess:

P(A|B) = P(A and B) / P(B).

We know P(A and B) is 0.55 x .26 = 0.143 or 14.3%. (I worked this out by solving for P(A and B) knowing what P(A|B) is but correct me if I'm wrong). So the first question I would ask is what exactly is it that we get if we subtract this 14.3% from 100%? The resulting 86%, is this the P(not A and not B) or is it something else?

Either way the formula we need for the answer is I think:

P(not A | not B) = P(not A and not B) / P(not B) ?

which is basically the negated version of the first formula.

But I'm not sure how to solve this.

Comment: What is $A$ and what is $B$ in your example? I see no reason to multiply $0.55$ and $0.26$. I think you are confusing some things. Slow down with your calculations and double think each one. First of all, you need to define what $A$ and $B$ are. Then, we can talk further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$A$ is the event that a person is smoke, and $B$ is the event that a person will die of lung disease.
$P(A \cap B)=P(B|A)P(A)=0.22$, but since $P(A)=0.4$ and $P(B)=0.26$ we can conclude the following probabilities:

$P(\bar{A})=0.6$, $P(\bar{B})=0.74$

$P(\bar{A} \cap B)=P(B)-P(A \cap B)=0.26-0.22=0.04$

$P(\bar{A} \cap \bar{B})=P(\bar{A})-P(\bar{A} \cap B)=0.6-0.04=0.56$

$P(\bar{B} | \bar{A})=\frac{P(\bar{B} \cap \bar{A})}{P(\bar{B})}=\frac{0.56}{0.6}=0.93$

I am willing to intoduce you to the strategy of solving such a question. We can built a table:
\begin{matrix}
P & A & \bar{A} & \\
B & 0.22 & 0.04 & 0.26 \\
\bar{B} &  & 0.56 & 0.74 \\
 & 0.4 & 0.6 & 1
\end{matrix}

as you can see, the positions in the table are the probabilities of the intersection of $A$ or $\bar{A}$ with $B$ or $\bar{B}$, the right column contains the probabilities $B$ and $\bar{B}$ and the last row contains the probabilities $A$ and $\bar{A}$.

I hope you noticed the sum of each row is in the last column and the sum of each column is in the last row. Moreover, the sum of the last row/column is $1$. So you can easily fill the table and use Bayes theorem, e.g. $P(A \cap B)=P(B|A)P(A)$, to calculate the conditional probabilities.

Hope this will help you...

Comment: Thanks this was also very helpful

Answer (score 0):

First, you made a mistake in calculating $P(A\cap B)$ in that you multiplied $P(A\mid B)$ by $P(A)$, not by $P(B)$. The $55\%$ are the probability $P(\text{die}\mid\text{smoke})$, so you need to multiply by $P(\text{smoke})$, not by $P(\text{die})$.

Indeed you want $P(\overline{\text{die}}\mid\overline{\text{smoke}})$, and this is

$$
P(\overline{\text{die}}\mid\overline{\text{smoke}})=\frac{P(\overline{\text{die}}\cap\overline{\text{smoke}})}{P(\overline{\text{smoke}})}
$$

You already have $P(\text{smoke})$, $P(\text{die})$ and $P(\text{die}\cap\text{smoke})$ so you can calculate

$$
P(\text{die}\cup\text{smoke})=P(\text{smoke})+P(\text{die})-P(\text{die}\cap\text{smoke})\;,
$$

and the numerator you need is the complement of that.

You also asked what you get if you subtract $P(A\cap B)$ from $1$. You get the complement, $P(\overline{A\cap B})$, which is $P(\overline A\cup\overline B)$. You might want to check out [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws).